# How to strip HTML from WooCommcerce Archive Description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, my theme displays descriptions for categories, archives, etc. I am trying to strip HTML from one of them, which is the WooCommerce Archive Description. The description is called with:

```
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

I need to apply the wp_strip_all_tags function to the do_action... is that possible? I know this is wrong, but something like:

```
<?php do_action( wp_strip_all_tags('woocommerce_archive_description') ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the tags in each of the functions attached to that action. Search your theme and plugins to find the functions. For instance, in woocommerce 2.0.20 there are two - `woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description` and `woocommerce_product_archive_description`. Since those function declarations have a check to see if they exist, you could override them by adding your own with the same name in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to replace:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>
```

with:

```
<?php echo $queried_object->description; ?>
```

I prefer to do it like this:

```
<?php echo '<h2 class="term-description">' . $queried_object->description . '</h2>'; ?>
```

Because I want to get rid of the paragraph tags surrounding the description and I want to replace the DIV whose class is "term-description" with an H2 and I'm fine to retain the original class.

Enjoy!

Kind Regards,
Mihai Bocsaru